# ASp.NET MVC: TryUpdateModel doesn't update all properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinder

I've got the following action:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var entity = new Employee();
    TryUpdateModel(entity, new[] { "Person.Name", "Code", "CompanyID" });
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = Service.MergeEmployee(entity);
        return RedirectToAction("List", new { success = true });
    }
    return View("Edit", new SupplierEmployeeModel() { Employee = entity });
}
```

What happens is that the property "Person.Name" doesn't get filled by the TryUpdateModel.

This is my form:

```
 <fieldset>
    <p>
        <label for="Name"><%=Strings.NAME %></label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("Person.Name", Model.Employee.Person.Name, new { Class = "text" })%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Name", "*") %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="CompanyID"><%=Strings.SUPPLIER %></label>
        <%= Html.DropDownList("CompanyID") %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("CompanyID", "*")%>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Code"><%=Strings.CODE %></label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("Code", Model.Employee.Code)%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Code", "*") %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= Html.Hidden("ID", Model.Employee.ID)%>
    </p>
    <div id="tabs-DE-actions" class="ui-dialog-buttonpane  ui-helper-clearfix" style="display: block;">
        <button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="submit"><%=Strings.SAVE%></button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the Person object is initialized in the Employee constructor; if it's null to begin with it is probably not updated properly.

```
public Employee()
{
    Person = new Person();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 TryUpdateModel(entity,"Person", new[] { "Name", "Code", "CompanyID" });
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fill in Person.Name, the model binder has to create a new Person. Have you given the model binder enough info to do that? Alternately, try creating the Person yourself before binding.

Comment: What is strange is that, if I instead of using the tryupdatemode use the Employee class as the action parameter (public ActionResult Create(Employee entity)) it binds correctly, with the Person.Name filled.